# Integer assignment

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I have a TableView Controller with an integer property. This property is declared in the interface of the header file like this :

```
int indexCurrentSousRubrique;
```

When I want to assign a value, the assignment doesn't work, the value is always equal to 0 :

[image: Integer assignment]

What's wrong ? I've never encontered this problem...

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Try to close and re-open Xcode ;) xCode sometimes has it's weird times.

Comment: Try making it a property. Also try a clean build.

Comment: I've re-open xCode, resolved !

Thank you @EmreAkman :)

Comment: If this is resolved, either write up the answer or close it.